# Waiting to start endorsing

Tags: node

I've recently set up my node and waiting until I can start endorsing. When I check my address on tzstats.com it shows next endorsing in 12 days and 15hrs. Is this the time when I can start endorsing on my node?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you see on tzstats is the time of your next endorsement right. You are granted "rights" by the network to bake and endorse based on the number of rolls you have. Each roll is 8K tez. You will always have more endorsement rights than baking rights. You should have the endorser software running on your node now. You may only have a few endorsement opportunities/rights this cycle.